# Groovy GString template engine use default engine

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins shared library.
I'm loading a groovy resource file which looks like this:

```
return [${Constants.nodeIP}@${Constants.username}]
```

The Constants class:

```
public class Constants{
    public static String nodeIP = "10.0.0.1"
    public static String username = "barel"
}
```

My purpose is to load the resource file into String and also subtitute the $ signs with the actual value.

```
import Constants

def template = libraryResource resource: 'myTemplate.txt'
def finalResult = """
    more text goes here
  
    $template

    and here
"""
println(finalResult)
```

Expected output is:

```
    more text goes here
  
    return [10.0.0.1@barel]

    and here
```

But I'm getting:

```
    more text goes here
  
    return [${Constants.nodeIP}@${Constants.username}]

    and here
```

The main point is that i need to pass the template through the template engine in order to substitute the values but for that I need to create an implicit mapping object and provide it to the template:

```
    def engine=new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
    def templateEngine = engine.createTemplate(template)
    def binding = [ "nodeIP" : "10.0.0.1", "username" : "barel"]
    templateEngine.make(binding)
```

I don't want to re-declare all fields when I'm using the template.
Is there any way to get a reference to the defaultive/built-in TemplateEngine which already has access to all project fields and properties?

Comment: I don't see where and what's declared in your case, but you cold pass just one context object as binding: `[context: this]`

Comment: I just want the template engine to look at the whole context and fill the template

Comment: I don't want to add each variable into the binding map manually

Comment: It's not possible